# Working example of the "Group by" in aggregations?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, aggregation

I'm having trouble figuring out the 
**Apps - Open Graph  - Aggregation - Advanced - Group By**
command.

I'd like to show the most popular links added to the open graph, grouped by an object property.  However, it only seems to show me one thing I can group on: the object type (not a property of the object type).

Has anyone gotten aggregation grouping working?  If so, can you explain what they mean by "These are evaluated in order. The first one to match is the grouping key." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only group by things with URLs. That is so that Facebook has somewhere to link to. so if you want o show the most popular links, you should make a "Link" object type and put that as a property of your other object. Then it should show up in the group by selector.